# Are more than 50% of integers below a positive x?

Tags: infinity, integers

If I have a positive `x`, are there more integers below `x` or above `x`?

I was discussing this with some friends and we came up with two opposing ideas:

1. No, since you can always count one more in either direction.
2. Yes, since the infinite amount of numbers below `x` is greater than the infinite amount of numbers above `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is countable.  Hence all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ are countably infinite, or finite.  There aren't different sizes of infinity in the subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ -- the only way you can get two subsets of different sizes is if at least one of them is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are an equal number of integers:
Denote the positive integer $n$. Then the two sets you are talking about are $S_1=\{x\mid x\in \mathbb{Z} \land x>n \}$ and $S_2=\{x\mid x\in \mathbb{Z} \land x<n \}$

Then consider the following function $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2, f(x) =2n-x$. This is a bijection because injective for obvious reason and surjective because for any $y<n$ we let $x=2n-y$ which is in our domain.